# iOS6 UIWebView Event Handling

Tags: jquery, events, uiwebview, hyperlink, ios6

I'm new to Stack Overflow, but not new to web development (~13 years).  I came across a bug yesterday at work and decided it was about time I joined the community.  ;)  I didn't see where to post that it's a bug I solved too, so I'm posting it as a question.  Please feel free to add your own comments and solutions.  I just figured this was a good one to post ASAP since iOS6 just came on the scene, and some of you may be panicking over this same issue.

The issue was in a UIWebView I developed for an extension to our iPad app.  It's content viewable through the in-app browser.  Well, we noticed the video and photo galleries stopped being clickable for iOS6 users.  Our click events on the images and divs weren't being fired for some reason.

Solution: I added blank link tags around each element not firing and it fixed the issue.

Side Note: Also, if any of you are having trouble getting the app store to open via links in your in-app browser content, just grab the direct link from the iTunes store via right-click on the app.

Comment: Hi @webninjataylor. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on Stackoverflow. When you've got a question that you are able to answer yourself, please create the question and then an answer to your own question. Otherwise your question will be displayed as unanswered and people won't be able to upvote your answer ([see this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12519/145712)).